# SSH Not Accepting Public Key

Tags: ssh, authentication, public-key

When setting up ssh keys between two machines, the authentication only works one way.  One server doesn't accept the public key of the other when trying to connect.  Any ideas?  Here's the verbose output.

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh_config
debug1: Rhosts Authentication disabled, originating port will not be trusted.
debug1: Connecting to xxxxxx.com [xx.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_3.6.1p2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'xxxxxx.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:17
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

**EDIT:** If it matters, this is for `root`

Comment: I am assuming root logins are allowed in your sshd_config?

Comment: Is this a problem specific to this server? Have you successfully set up ssh key authorization before?

Comment: There are other accounts authenticating in this fashion just fine, just not root

Comment: I ended up using a different account that was working and sudoing.  Ok, not as elegant, but I'd spent enough time on this.

Comment: Check SSHD logs in my case I did `rsync` with `-a` option and by mistake I changed ownership of `/root` folder and that leads to not accepting my already trusted pubkey

Comment: @Gelldur that was exactly my problem! Thank you so much! this was very hard to pinpoint...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the values of the following options on the ssh server:

```
PubkeyAuthentication Yes
RSAAuthentication Yes
PermitRootLogin Yes
```

Comment: RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

Comment: Check if PermitRootLogin is not set to no, if it set to no set it to nopwd

Comment: It was set to `yes` and I changed it to `without-password` and restarted ssh without any effect whatsoever -- it still asked for a password.  That, my friend, is determination.

Comment: @radius there is no nopwd. And setting it to without-password is only making it a bit more secure, in that they'd still need a key. And anyhow keys come first anyway. If he can't get in with a key, he still won't be able to get in with a key.  I don't know, maybe he hadn't copied his public key over, or maybe he wasn't logging in as the right user on the ssh server.

Comment: -1 This solution do not work. Besides this contains a deprecated option.

Answer (score 13):

I've just had a case where SELinux prevented sshd from reading the /root/.ssh/authorized_keys file. /var/log/messages will show you that the sshd process was denied access for read operation on the authorized_keys file.

After I ran `restorecon -v /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, SSH with the public-key worked fine.

Comment: My logs showed nothing about denying access but I ran this command anyway. And what do you know, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Same as @Kaivosukeltaja, nothing in the logs, but the command works.

Answer (score 8):

Changing StrictModes to "no" in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` worked for me.

```
sysadmin@suselinux1:~> con sysadmin kaiser
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-25-generic i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Fri Nov  9 15:40:11 2012 from 10.1.3.25
sysadmin@kaiser:~$ date
vie nov  9 17:53:11 CST 2012
sysadmin@kaiser:~$
```

Comment: Instead of disabling `StrictModes` you could fix the file permissions of files in `.ssh` (and the `.ssh` directory itself) instead.

Comment: @Flimm How?....

Comment: @Brethlosze `chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys*` and `chmod 0700 ~/.ssh`

Answer (score 6):

Check the permission and owner of the .ssh folder, authorized_key file and the home folder, the /var/log/auth.log will give you more messages when you try to login.

Comment: `/var/log/auth.log` on the server, not the client (in case someone assumes the latter).

Comment: And... how those permission should be fixed?

Answer (score 3):

In case others run into the same problem I did, which took me an embarrassingly long time to figure out; always use `ssh-copy-id` where available to install your public key.

Call this from the client you are trying to configure for passwordless login, like so:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -p <port_number> <username>@<host>
```

Swapping `port_number` (if customised) and the `username` and `host` of the user you're trying to connect to on the remote host.

This will avoid any inconsistencies when copying across your public key by other means, as even a single incorrect or unexpected character will prevent login, and it's surprisingly easy to do it wrong!

Answer (score 2):

I want to put forth my finding for future Googlers--I tried `PermitRootLogin yes` and context changing but none worked. Also, in CentOS 7 the correct log to look at seems to be `tail -f /var/log/secure`. There is no `auth.log` in my server.

Anyway, after looking at `/var/log/secure`, I realize the following line:

> Jul  1 00:01:46 my-server sshd[113597]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /home/minion/.ssh/authorized_keys

Motivated by that, after changing `~/.ssh` to `0700` and `authorized_keys` to `0600`, `sshd` server accepts my public key.

Answer (score 1):

My key was not being forwarded, turned out I had started the SSH agent in a different terminal window, so the `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable was not available in the terminal in which I was making the connection.

So if you are starting the agent manually, make sure you make the connection in the same terminal session.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issues was with the incorrect shell exec.

```
journalctl -f
....
Feb 25 11:45:54 59a02b89e0f6 sshd[]: User user not allowed because shell /usr/bin/env /bin/bash does not exist
....
```

Changed /etc/passwd file for that user

```
vi /etc/passwd 
....
user:x:1000:1000::/home/user:/bin/bash
....
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had extended the permissions of the user's home dir such that its group also has write permissions (775 instead of the usual 755). Looking at `/var/log/auth.log` revealed the cause after many other attempts, as suggested by @Andy Zhang.